# Is it possible to say that $\{ X | X\subseteq A\} \cap \{ X | X\subseteq B\} = \{ X | X\subseteq A \land X\subseteq B\} $?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Is it possible to say that $\{ X | X\subseteq A\} \cap \{ X | X\subseteq B\} = \{ X | X\subseteq A \land X\subseteq B\}  $ 
I was thinking about it for a while and it seems quite intuitive, however, I don't know what kind of axioms or theorems I could use to prove this. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. This is a direct consequence of the definition of set intersection ($\cap$) which is: if $P$ and $Q$ are any properties, then $$\{ x\mid P(x)\}\cap\{x\mid Q(x)\} = \{x\mid P(x)\land Q(x)\}.$$

This is the definition of $\cap$.

In your example $P(x)$ is $x\subseteq A$ and $Q(x)$ is $x\subseteq B$.

---

The formulas above can be abbreviated a bit: $$z \in R\cap S \iff z\in R \land z \in S$$ but this really adds nothing new, because the definition of $\in$ is that $z \in \{x \mid P(x)\}$ if and only if $P(z)$ is true (that is, if $z$ has the property $P$).

Answer (score 1):

Since $\{ X | X\subseteq A\} \cap \{ X | X\subseteq B\}$ is a set and $\{ X | X\subseteq A \land X\subseteq B\}$ is another set, no, you cannot say that they are equivalent (well, yes, you can say it, but it makes no sense). Equivalence is for propositions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
However, I'm really sorry - I wrote $\iff$ but I meant to write $=$.